# Area 51 site summary - can it show what % of traffic comes from search engines?

Tags: feature-request, area-51

[Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) just popped over the 500 visits/day mark and I took a look at the [Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel) to celebrate. The visits paragraph says:

> Okay – 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some
>   work. A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually,
>   90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines

That raises the obvious question, of the 527 visits/day, how many are from search engines? Is it just a small core of people talking amongst themselves or is it starting to reach the wider internet?

So, is this information available and if so can it be exposed on Area 51 or the stats box on the beta sites themselves?

Answer (score 1):

This information is available to the moderators at https://travel.stackexchange.com/admin/analytics#trafficSource.  This page displays information  about activity levels for various site activities, page views, traffic sources, and referrers.  The page does have the headline

> analytics data is intended for moderators only; please don't share the specifics of this data in public

so I can't tell you about the specifics.  I can tell you that at [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), just around 10% of our traffic comes from direct visits (typing in the URL to my address bar, clicking a bookmark, etc), and 10% more comes from people following links posted on other (non-search-engine) sites, and the remaining 80% is search engine traffic.  The month after we entered private beta, we had less than half of our present traffic levels, and about half of our traffic came from direct visits and links on the SE network.

This isn't something that you can fix by flipping a switch.  The #1 best way to improve this statistic is to generate quality content - Answer and ask questions, edit and improve existing questions and tags, and generate a vibrant community with a high quality corpus of Q&A.  Lots of people like to travel, and are searching for queries that should be on your site.  Generate the answers to these queries, and your traffic numbers will improve.

Comment: I know that growing traffic takes time, and I know that questions and answers are our only tools to do so. I was just looking for more "output" to put into the feedback - we see the visits climb, but we don't know what fraction of those came new from search engines. I would like to know that.